# When using HalvingRandomSearchCV I get the error "UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm trying to predict Age (→ `Y`). Previously, I used ElasticNet, however to no avail.
Currently I'm trying to use sklearn's `RandomForestRegressor` (which works when I'm using `RandomizedSearchCV`), however `HalvingRandomSearchCV` turns out to be substantially faster.
That's why I'm trying to upgrade my program to use `HalvingRandomSearchCV` but doing so creates the error "*UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite*" - 4 times in total. ([See error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyOAf.jpg))

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67535904/userwarning-one-or-more-of-the-test-scores-are-non-finite-warning-only-when-a) it's suggested that this is due to the parameters in `random_grid`. I manipulated these and couldn't resolve the error that way.
Next I looked into `rf_random.cv_results_`. I found that `mean_test_score`, `split2_test_score` and `std_test_score` are the test scores with `NaN` values. In all cases the first 72 entries are `NaN` and the values match the printed error messages.
Yet, I can't find the 1st array to raise the error, which should contain only `NaNs`.

What's also weird is that the same parameters result in different outcomes.
When looking at `rf_random.cv_results_["params"]` I find that using the [same parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLN2V.jpg) results in `NaN` for the 3rd setting of parameters and (e.g.) `-9.7` for the 72th setting of parameters.

*Final remarks*:

- X is a (656,91) DataFrame and contains z-score transformed data.
- Y is a (656, 1) DataFrame and contains the Age as a float in years.
- Right now my code also raises the "*UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples.*" warning. To my understanding this is a separate issue and will be the next thing I'll fix.

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.experimental import enable_halving_search_cv  # noqa
from sklearn.model_selection import HalvingRandomSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

def RandomForestCVRandomSearch(X, Y, n_splits_outer_cv = 3, n_splits_inner_cv = 3):

    n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 200, stop = 2000, num = 10)]
    max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']                                                 
    max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 100, num = 10)]                 
    max_depth.append(None)                                                          
    min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]                                                  
    min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]                                                    
    bootstrap = [True, False]                                                       

    # Create the random grid
    random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
               'bootstrap': bootstrap}


    cv_outer = KFold(n_splits = n_splits_outer_cv, random_state=1, shuffle=True)

    for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(cv_outer.split(X)):
    
        x_train, x_test = X.loc[train_index,:], X.loc[test_index,:]
        y_train, y_test = Y.loc[train_index,:], Y.loc[test_index,:]

        rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)
        rf_random = HalvingRandomSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid,
                                      cv = n_splits_inner_cv, verbose=2, random_state=42, n_jobs = -1)
    
        rf_random.fit(x_train.to_numpy(), y_train.to_numpy().ravel())
        rf_score = rf_random.score(x_test.to_numpy(), y_test.to_numpy())
```

**Update:**
While the error itself is not clear to me - yet - I overlooked the importance of the "*UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples.*" warning.
A fix to the problem is to change the scoring strategy:

```
rf_random = HalvingRandomSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid,
                                      cv = n_splits_inner_cv, verbose=2, random_state=42, 
                                      n_jobs = -1, scoring = 'explained_variance')
```

**Update 2**
It might be that a bad interaction between my nested CV and the internal CV of `HalvingRandomSearchCV` caused the issue. As I wrote before `n_resources` is 6 in the first iteration and we believe that the resources are split across the CV (=3). So that we end up with 2 resources in each fold - which is not enough to calculate an R2-score. That would also explain why in the second iteration, where `n_resources` increases, the issue doesn't appear.

Comment: What's the rest of `cv_results_` look like?  Especially, are the NaNs for a consistent range of `n_resources` and/or parameters?

Comment: @BenReiniger I checked all keys for patterns here's what I found:
**iter**: all `NaN` test scores have a value of 0. Max value is 3 for the best 3 fits.
**n_resources**: all `NaN` test scores have a value of 6. Max value is 162 for the best 3 fits. I don't understand what you mean with "consistent range", but as you can see in the error message, the `NaNs` are a consistent span, as in the first 72 entries are `NaN` and this is reflected in the test scores and in iter & n_resources.
As far as I can tell the rest of `cv_results_` is unsuspious? Anything I should be on the look out for?

Comment: It seems likely connected to the r2 warning, and that the smallest-data iteration is somehow providing too few test points to give an r2.  But the behavior of `min_resources` for a regressor is exactly `2*cv`, matching the 6 you're seeing, and that should provide 2 rows for every test fold.  Maybe somehow the actual cross-validation split generator isn't working correctly?

Comment: @BenReiniger It actually is, wow. I changed the scoring strategy to `explained_variance` and now it works. I also tried manipulating the cv, however that changed nothing. For now I have a working programm (and some voodoo in my code) - thank you.

Comment: Other potential fixes include setting `min_resources` to something larger than 6, or to "exhaust". But the issue is still worth figuring out, maybe a bug to be submitted.  Can you provide your data, or a smaller version that gives the same issue?

Comment: @BenReiniger sadly I do not have the latitude to share any of the data. But a colleague was able to help me out: It seems that a bad interaction between my nested CV and the internal CV of `HalvingRandomSearchCV` caused the issue.
As I wrote before `n_resources` is 6 in the first iteration and we believe that the resources are split across the CV (=3). So that we end up with 2 resources in each fold - which is not enough to calculate an R2-score.   
That would also explain why in the second iteration, where `n_resources` increases, the issue doesn't appear.

Comment: That doesn't seem right to me; the halving search is using the inner folds, so those should be constructed with at least 2 test samples...

Comment: @BenReiniger Do you have another idea why increasing `min_resources` fixes the problem?

Comment: It seems clear that it is an issue of some folds getting to small a dataset, which agrees with larger `min_resources` fixing it. I worry that the actual splitter has some bug.